# How to get the ampere information from the battery charger using Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Is there any method to get the ampere of the battery charger programmatically with kotlin?

I have seen scripts that use BatteryManger to pick up useful information about battery level, voltage, etc. But none of the information I've found is useful for picking up the ampere information from the charger

Comment: Which battery charger? For your car? For wireless headphones?

Comment: For my smartphone Android

Answer (score 0):

[This is from the official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager)

Battery capacity in microampere-hours, as an integer.

> int    BATTERY_PROPERTY_CHARGE_COUNTER

Average battery current in microamperes, as an integer.

> int   BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_AVERAGE

Instantaneous battery current in microamperes, as an integer.

> int   BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_NOW

**With these values you should be able to get what you are looking for.
Remember these are values you should convert to ampere since they are in microamperes.**

If this doesn't help you, please let me know and I'll provide more support.

Happy coding!

---

*EDIT*

*I don't think there is a proper way to get charger informations without a proper SDK, BUT if there is a method and someone knows how it would be great!*